# Mysql, changing file location to remote in local network

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have 4 computers and 1 server in my local network, there is Xampp(with Mysql) installed on each computer, what I'd like to do, is to cofigure it the way  that all mysql data from all computers be saved on the server, so each computer will be talking to the server

Comment: sounds like a plan. One mysql server. You guys can have 1 central place for it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could install mysql on the server, and point all php development to access database on the server. instead of local host.
this should be as easy as changing the database configuration part of your php 
just be sure to create user for remote access in the mysql server.

if each computer client have already data in their local database, then dump all databases and recreate on the server.